# New Site Design!

Tags: code-golf, string

Unless you have a userscript that modifies the site's design (or even if so), you should have noticed that we have our site design!

<sub><sup>[(It's November now)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50642664#50642664)</sup></sub>

So, to celebrate, let's make a program that retroactively applies this design (oversimplified, of course)!

So, the most important changes are:

- our new name is now Code Golf and Coding Challenges
- our site is no longer the default blue color and is instead a nice dark green

So, given a string, change:

- `PPCG` to `CGCC`
- `Programming Puzzles {non-whitespace} Code Golf` to `Code Golf {same-thing} Coding Challenges` (for example, `Programming Puzzles + Code Golf`, `and Code Golf`, and `& Code Golf` would all be changed to `Code Golf + Coding Challenges`, `and Coding Challenges`, and `& Coding Challenges`.
- `#abc` to `#acb` (swap blue to green and vice versa - just ignore the fact that green shouldn't logically become blue but I don't want to complicate the color shifting)
- `#abcdef` to `#abefcd` (same as above)

Note that for the color swaps, you should accept any hexadecimal digit from `0-9` to `a-f`. You can choose what case of hex digit to require, but it must be consistent and the same from input to output.

Your substitutions can be case-sensitive, and if not, please specify how the output works.

The substitutions should only happen when the string is surrounded by word boundaries (including the start of the `#`). In other words, each of the specified substitutions should only occur if the match is at the edge of the string or is bordered by non-alphanumeric characters (on both sides).

Standard loopholes apply. This is a code-golf challenge, so the shortest code wins!

## Examples

```
PPCG -> CGCC
Programming Puzzles or Code Golf -> Code Golf or Coding Challenges
PPCG stands for Programming Puzzles and Code Golf and its site color is #abf -> CGCC stands for Code Golf and Coding Challenges and its site color is #afb
The color #00f is much more intense than #5568ed -> The color #0f0 is much more intense than #55ed68
Programming Puzzles and No Substitution -> Programming Puzzles and No Substitution
No Substitution and Code Golf -> No Substitution and Code Golf
Programming Puzzles and no substitution Code Golf -> Programming Puzzles and no substitution Code Golf
Code Golf and Programming Puzzles -> Code Golf and Programming Puzzles
Programming Puzzles and Programming Puzzles and Code Golf -> Programming Puzzles and Code Golf and Coding Challenges
```

(for the last test case, it is important to note that the translated string could be translated again but the transformation must be applied *exactly* once)

## Important Update

(Thanks @tsh)

The `Programming Puzzles ... Code Golf` substitution rule can include the other rules inside of it (`Programming Puzzles PPCG Code Golf` is valid). In this case, you may choose whether or not the rules are applied, but it must be deterministic. I'm not requiring that you be consistent between `PPCG` and `#...` because answers seem to implement the rules in my list ordering which results in inconsistencies. This is just a clarification; I believe all current answers remain valid.

Comment: Should be apply the substitutions only if there are word boundaries around the substrings or everywhere?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Good catch; should have word boundaries. I will specify that; thanks.

Comment: Define "word boundary" for a #; regex implementations generally don't consider a # to start a word.

Comment: @tomsmeding I'm just going to make it so that the substitutions have to be at the edge of the string or have non-alnum around it

Comment: Got test cases?

Comment: @ValueInk added some, thanks

Comment: May one keyword appear multiple times in a testcase? May some testcases doesn't contain any of these words? If so, I would suggest that include at least one of such thing.

Comment: Is `Programming Puzzles #123 Code Golf`, `Programming Puzzles PPCG Code Golf` valid testcases? What is expected to be outputed?

Comment: @tsh I never thought about that, good catch. Since the answers are inconsistent between the two, I'm going to say that you can choose whether or not the joiner for `Programming Puzzles ... Code Golf` gets modified. Thanks.

Comment: @Veskah Will add, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I guess `Programming Puzzles and no substitution Code Golf` might also catch someone (even though everyone's using the same valid regex)

Comment: @Veskah That's a good one too, though I don't think that would happen (`\S` is a bit too easy to screw up :P). I'll add it anyway

Comment: Suggested test cases `Code Golf and Programming Puzzles` and `Programming Puzzles and Programming Puzzles and Code Golf`. @Veskah Hmm, and I think that last suggested test case fails in my 05AB1E answer, since I don't have regex.. >.< Back to the drawing board..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added, thanks

Comment: Suggested test case: `color-#00f-` (not surrounded by whitespace). Also, `\b` in regexes is usually `A-Za-z0-9_`, so do we need to include the `_`  as well (since you mention non-alphanumeric, I could interpret this as not; which would invalid almost all answers). Or is either with or without fine?

Comment: I didn't think it would happen during my lifetime.

Comment: @coredump lol... I mean, it only took 4-6 weeks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 85 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ì▀¼FΣ¼≤C╛╓ÄydîNû►┘Δ▲Bd♫|α╒oñFτ▒t!↑▌╩┘♦pMc6Hèé▄·│╝∙↔¥^4b5╠·9█&╨^╨♂═î£ε■å±«\┴J₧å♠Å≡z╜û♀
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ddfac46e4acf343bed68e79648c4e9610d9ff1e42640e7ce0d56fa446e7b1742118ddcad904704d6336488a82dcfab3bcf91d9d5e346235ccfa39db26d05ed00bcd8c9ceefe86f1ae5cc14a9e86068ff07abd960c&i=PPCG%0AProgramming+Puzzles+or+Code+Golf%0APPCG+stands+for+Programming+Puzzles+and+Code+Golf+and+its+site+color+is+%23abf%0AThe+color+%2300f+is+much+more+intense+than+%235568ed%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 12):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>165</s> <s>164</s> 159 bytes

It ended up being very similar to the sed answer, but it abuses Ruby's string interpolation to duplicate the hex group matching `([\da-f]{1,2})` within the third regex three times instead of needing to repeat the whole thing again.

- *-1 byte from @randomdude999.*
- *-5 bytes from leveraging @Xcali's Perl solution*

```ruby
gsub /\bPPCG\b/,"CGCC"
gsub /\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\b/,'\2\1Coding Challenges'
[1,2].map{|i|gsub /(^|\s)#\K#{'([\da-f]{%d})'%i*3}\b/,'\2\4\3'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xboMwEIZ3nuIUKwKapAmQRN09MHRBarc4lUywwRLYiDNDA7x6KbRKsmS87@7772/a9Hscc2xT2LI0SWjM0u16QWNKF84dNyZveFUpnUPSXq@lQA/Yxwp8j5pMQGxK6c@ey0IWTGg@pAUvS6Fzga5zCtbh@bXidder/j/V@@oZ@oS9k871TizjG3nultngu0v1Eg23tD2L3GEcnzQA08D9uzM3B7RcZwhy2jwTpuXD@JuURUBlBVxMOUkKgfBUOp/FjZDdTs64ai8FVKYRoLQVGgXYgmsgh8PxTWRAgjDayx9TW2U0jpv6Fw)

Comment: Doesn't using `{1,2}` break with hex inputs of length 4 or 5, e.g. `#aabbc`? Edit: [it does](https://tio.run/##PYy7DoIwFEB3v@JKh4JKFIzGwcShAyuJbl4HHpdHUlrSwqDGX7c@YlxPzjlmzK/O1XbMYYl5mooE8@XCE4kQ3uSPja5N1nWtqiEdbzdJ1gc8zgPwhS4JEi2r4NNxjDGCN/uYosmkJFWT5b@Tf9hP8Rgwduf@GcssrC73aBE/Aj5bP749wwjXGHPnTg1BoaU2IVutKmgtdGPRQKcNQasGUpZgaDIFbLPZ7qh86n5otbIu7F8) (this example should not be replaced because it's not a valid hex color).

Comment: Fails for [this case](https://tio.run/##PYy7DoIwFEB3v@JKh4JKFIzGwcShAyuJbl4HHpdHUlrSwqDGX7c@YlxPzjlmzK/O1XbMYYl5mooE8@XCE4kQ3uSPja5N1nWtqiEdbzdJ1gc8zgPwhS4JEi2r4NNxjDGCN/uYosmkJFWT5b@Tf9hP8Rgwduf@GcssrC73aBE/Aj5bP749wwjXGHPnTg1BoaU2IVutKmgtdGPRQKcNQasGUpZgaDIFbLPZ7qh86n5otbIu7F8) (`-` is a non-alphanumeric character).

Comment: @randomdude999 yeah, good catch. Added a check for that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yeah, I guess. "Word boundaries" with the `#` is a bit ambiguous since `/\b/` doesn't register with it next to another non-alphanumeric, but I did the change anyways for no byte change (replacing `\S` with `\w`)

Comment: Can't you replace your `(?<!\w)` with my `(^|\W)` for 1 char?

Comment: 1 more byte can be saved by changing `...Puzzles( \S+) (Code...` -> `...Puzzles (\S+ )(Code...` and `...'\2\1 Coding...` -> `...'\2\1Coding...`

Comment: @tomsmeding `(^|\W)` is an additional matching group that must be outputted again at the end, so it saves 1 byte there but adds 3 to the gsub output (`$1+`), for a total of +2 bytes gain.

Comment: @randomdude999 fixed, thanks! Although, the match was supposed to be `( \S+ )`, not `(\S+ )` ;)

Answer (score 9):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>270</s> <s>285</s> 283 bytes

Thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for pointing out a bug.

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```cpp
#import<regex>
#import<string>
auto f=[](auto s){typeof(s)R[][2]{"bPPCG","CGCC","bProgramming Puzzles( \\S+ )(Code Golf)","$2$1Coding Challenges","B#(?=([\\da-f]{3}){1,2}\\b)(.+?)(..??)(..??)","#$2$4$3"};for(auto r:R)s=std::regex_replace(s,std::regex('\\'+*r+"\\b"),r[1]);return s;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNj5swED2HXzGCqLEbstpkm6oKhEjlkGu07Q1Q5RhDkMBGtpG6i/jt6QDa5rKX5/l4bzzzeNtuSs7vXiV53eUCwkoZqwVrIudRY1qztwhJTau0DbUoxd@xP6fIr2QZOayzCopjkpEpMrS3b61QBTH0NcmSXda718slPru@G5/jGJ/rRatSs6ZBPVy69/daGAJp@msNlMQKvz6ruqDIXO6WWyyMvPjG6lrIUhis//TI6UiSNM3Zpsj6l4H2W383pOmVkqf1CeHp9IFI93DOt@WLOwSF0vOa@vBKzdHY/HCY7vqjRVszLojxH0WyStPV@qteuzjZpb5OthkNtLCdlmCCIbhX0kLDKkmo0zuLSTm5Fk7hbJEP@wisMNb07mwEuJ84AErD/@MnDnLBWCZzA7g3fKbB5kM0ZZU1YCorgKsaRZUBj12neb9vH0Xv@bkYO03Hb9AoLQDvENIIsDcmwdvvv/8Q@ajxCobDETnmQ@AsnMW4CuFKGgujk1/AwmE@jzqL2QKuOgthCBO4sIkQMCqIpeO7SuUqcIb7Pw)

Comment: Seems to mangle `#fade` and `#faced` which it should not.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>153</s> 130 bytes

```
\bPPCG\b
CGCC
\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\b
$2$1Coding Challenges
\B(#(?=([\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b).+?)(..??)(..??)\b
$1$4$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49a8MwEN31Kw7sQSKpiZMmZCmGavBqaLeogxyfbIEsgaQsCfntrhRIu2Q5eF/3nseorVwW0Xcdb0VPeMs5Sci70ct51naE7nK9GgwUxNcKGOVuQGidUSzZy21ZJyLb@CSNQTtiIOKTFrT5oCcxyDf1c9vd2a1eb@@iZ9WqYbSqmufNP@ryvdwtS15AXhSD8/BXSrILQpR2CKCS8iqQxP/EA@kYIOiIcHYmhXSAQvaKfE9PpthsVKbny3mC2XkEbSPagBAnaaHY7w9HHH4B) Link includes test cases. All substitutions are case sensitive. Assumes normal regex word characters are acceptable so that `\B#` matches only `#`s that don't follow a word character. Edit: Saved 22 bytes thanks to @tsh.

Comment: Try `\B#(?=([\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b)(.+?)(..??)(..??)\b`?

Answer (score 5):

## GNU sed `-E`, 198 chars

```
s/\bPPCG\b/CGCC/g
s/\bProgramming Puzzles( \S* Cod)e Golf\b/Code Golf\1ing Challenges/g
s/((^|\W)#[0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])\b/\1\4\3/g
s/((^|\W)#[0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})\b/\1\4\3/g
```

Runnable using e.g. `sed -E 'the above'`; newlines can either be included literally, or replaced with `;` if you so wish. Both work.

@HyperNeutrino come on that word boundary rule is stupid. Look what I had to do in the `#` case.

Yes, I didn't even try. :P

+9 by @Value Ink

Comment: [Flags are no longer included in byte counts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52194) so you can take out the extra byte and call it "GNU sed `-E`" instead.

Comment: @ValueInk Whaaaaat? I have apparently been severely out of touch with this community for too long to not notice that. I think it's a good rule though. Also, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: doesn't `sed`'s regex matching allow using `\d` as a shortcut for `0-9`? could save you a whole 6 bytes

Comment: Also I just noticed, you return "Programming Puzzles or Coding Challenges" for the second test case instead of the expected "Code Golf or Coding Challenges".

Comment: @randomdude999 The re_format(7) man page on my Mac seems to suggest that sed should support \d, but apparently it doesn't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hm, just checked and indeed Posix extended regular expressions do not support single-letter character classes. Probably re_format/7) documents syntax of Perl regular expressions, not Posix extended REs.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>123</s> <s>109</s> <s>105</s> <s>110</s> 114 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žKISå_Å¡JεÐć'#QsžhA6£«sSåP*i3äćsRJ«ë"PPCG"Qi"CGCC"]J”–±ÇÀ”DU¡ćsε”ƒËŠˆ”©¡DVćDÁ2ôεðå}ćs_P*YyÊP*i”Âïªï”«s®ý«®ìëyXì]J«
```

+5 bytes fixing test cases like `Programming Puzzles and no substitution Code Golf` and `Programming Puzzles and Programming Puzzles and Code Golf`.
+4 bytes fixing test cases like `color-#00f` (colors with something besides spaces/newlines surrounding it). Thanks to *@Grimy* for bringing this to my attention.

Case-sensitive. Hexadecimal values are with lowercase `abcdef`; `Programming Puzzles ... Code Golf` is in titlecase; `PPCG` is in full uppercase.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##hVHBSsNAEL3nK5bkIBQCRWnxKikUK0hqVfRQStomzUKyC9nk0IJQBQ3oRfQsWLQHTbEK9mgPO60XoR/RH4mbgtRKi5dlZt5782ZmKTOq2Izj8XBnuwTdCpzzTmEygOtRuKYU2Xhob2X5A4@YAPUU3oDHUcj2CjyCSNZ1LS8XsazlNU0uF6btu2n7lr9BCG0R5w54R3AnAxF/3sDV@P7rQoT8iXdyh6MwB6fr8C6cXqF7IngVPXXchEvhIUhwBn3@DP2EHzH@Ah88Em8PouYR9MrCPo5leTaApHu04Rmui0kD6UGr5ZgMUQ9ptG6iPHUsKWEh5hukzpAlkGUCAc4Vswz7DDHsm6hGHSHCDClG1ZL27Z@Kkk5bSdkNajZyqWciTHyTMBP5tkGQkslkN826tMptl6JSUGU@9gMfUyL9yRcnWtmFUMR@q@aKxW2W6Ff2/Pc@0uwAanIA8QmxqhKqOkar@Q0)

Definitely not the right language for the job.. Mimicking word-boundaries and replacing `Programming Puzzles \S+ Code Golf`, but not `Code Golf \S+ Programming Puzzles` or `Programming Puzzles \S+ \S+ Code Golf` without any regexes is pretty hard (to do short).. >.>

**Explanation:**

```python
žK                # Push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
                  # (NOTE: if '_' also count as word boundary, use `žj` instead)
  IS              # Push the input as a list of characters
    å_            # Check for each character if they are NOT in the string
      Å¡          # Split the (implicit) input on truthy values
        J         # Join each inner character list to a string again
ε                 # Map each word to:
 Ð                #    Triplicate the word
  ć               #    Extract head; push remainder and head separately to the stack
   '#Q           '#    Check if the head equals "#"
    žh            #    Push string "0123456789"
      A6£«        #    Append the first 6 letters of the alphabet: "0123456789abcdef"
   s      sSåP    #    Check if the characters of the remainder are all in this string
   *i             #    If both are truthy:
     3ä           #     Split the 'word' into three parts
                  #      i.e. "#ab12cd" → ["#ab","12","cd"]
       ćs         #     Extract head, and swap
         R        #     Reverse the remainder list
          J«      #     Join them together, and merge them to the head again
    ë"PPCG"Qi     #    Else-if the word is "PPCG":
     "CGCC"       #     Push "CGCC"
                  #    (Implicit else:
                  #      Use the word that's still there from the initial triplicate)
]                 # Close all if statements and the nested map
 J                # Join the mapped words together again
”–±ÇÀ”            # Push dictionary string "Programming Puzzles"
      DU          # Save a copy in variable `X`
        ¡         # Split the string by this
         ćs       # Extract head & swap; pushing head and remainder to the stack
ε                 # Map each substring `y` in the remainder to:
 ”ƒËŠˆ”           #  Push dictionary string "Code Golf"
       ©          #  Save it in variable `®` (without popping)
        ¡         #  Split the current substring we're mapping by it
         DV       #  Save a copy of this list in variable `Y`
           ćD     #  Extract the head and duplicate
                  #  (so the stack is: remainder, head, head)
 Á                #  Rotate the characters in the head-string once towards the right
  2ô              #  Split it into parts of size 2
    εðå}          #  Check in each part if it contains a space
        ćs        #  Extract head and swap again
          _       #  Check if all values are 0
           P      #  And check if this is truthy for all
          *       #  And check if this is truthy, as well as the head
                  #  (this means the current string has a leading and trailing space,
                  #   and no other spaces)
 YyÊP             #   Check that none of the susbtrings in variable `Y`
                  #   are equal to the current substring `y`
 *i               #   If both checks above are truthy:
   ”Âïªï”«        #    Prepend "Coding Challenges" to the duplicated head
          s®ý     #    Join the remainder by variable `®` ("Code Golf")
             «    #    Append it
              ®ì  #    And prepend an additional variable `®` ("Code Golf")
  ë               #   Else:
   y              #    Simply keep the substring `y` as is
    Xì            #    And prepend variable `X` ("Programming Puzzles") 
                  #    since we've split by it
]                 # Close all if-else statements and the map
 J                # Join the mapped substrings together to a single string
  «               # And append it to the initially extracted head
                  # (then output the resulting string implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”–±ÇÀ”` is `"Programming Puzzles"`; `”ƒËŠˆ”` is `"Code Golf"`; and `”Âïªï”` is `"Coding Challenges"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 240 bytes

```python
import re
lambda x,s=re.sub,b='(?<!\w)',e='(?!\w)',h='([\da-f]',t=r'#\1\3\2':s(b+'#%s{2})'%h+h+'{2})%s{2})'%h+e,t,s(b+'#%s)'%h+h+')%s)'%h+e,t,s(b+'Programming Puzzles( \S+ Cod)e Golf'+e,r'Code Golf\1ing Challenges',s(b+'PPCG'+e,'CGCC',x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VBRS8MwEH7vrzgpmpbWsk3mhlhE@rDXgYIP1od0vTSBNBlJxpzib59Jt6kP@wcGQr67@77vLrfeOa7VZL8X/VobBwYjSfumpfCe29JgYTdN3pQkebi/qLcpyTHgA@QevtYtvWZvJHelIXE9rm/qCbmzSZOR@NJ@Tr5ScskznpEAfxOYu/xEOjHSI/ypLY3uDO17oTpYbj4@JNoE6qcMKt2mCAstGfFsQ3x8COtx4FacSomqQ0uORstqEZikWlQVyd9Tf/as/B8fjdZGKAcsCX/c2cK6VqjCIG0Tv4WgKM/0h@xqaH9oV8ALFxLBcQQtW1hpqQ0wf30mWIS3R9hSC/FkNZtNZ5AYvem43EF8M5um@aBVuAWtkNh4TOd0PB@NiugRGiM67o6mwjswZL4QBePo3Gye9jPawALrqGrtMNE5gS/@KoZIOAtWOPzTlTYseuanTDwasZDuNysOvTYIfouobFgCVRBPp7dzbL8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 174 bytes

```javascript
s=>s[R='replace'](/\bPPCG\b/g,'CGCC')[R](/\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\b/g,'$2$1Coding Challenges')[R](/\B#(?=([\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b)(.+?)(..??)(..??)\b/ig,'#$2$4$3')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNNb@IwEIbv@RUjBcm2CikfJWWFAlJz4Iq6eyNIdRI7uHJsFLt7KOK3szbZsJS2K8Vjzzszz7yXvNLf1BSN2NuB0iU78eRkkoXZPCeoYXtJC4a2@D7L1@t0leX3VR@lqzRFZPPcyo2uGlrXQlWwfnt/l8xgyH7eAcGpw8FKS07aud64N3Ka70x3VEqmKmY60FOIlwneZCUd8O1hciSHUX98zHKCo7ulC9Gyiw4mHC10uIfeBJHT/CXw5mCwAG8t@MIS6AYuds6Nl6StfDTV8oylqjTAXcdXSFe8wvhMWANGWAaFlm5IGAhpzjtf17yPc5/2f0vjefBr1ynhcMi9XL8VO6h1w0Aoy5RhYHdUQTidxjNW@vXXM3z4/xlWxrMghHDkvrE/k3N4aOP07xV39@PlMfv3@uGXXjEm40@MaXxJv2EEL5FtRI1JZPZSWIwyhUhU0z2WkCzgEBRaGQsb0WdbSEB2bX43IvNzWUsWSV1hcZNzp9xI7CZHAxS5H4BRix9jQoIjmZ/@AA)

Comment: Fails on test case `#abcde` because the regex qualifier `{3,6}` matches between 3 and 6 characters, instead of either 3 or 6 which I assume you were going for.

Comment: @ValueInk nice catch. fixed with +5 bytes.

Comment: Might be shorter to use a replace function over the long regex

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>177</s> <s>173</s> <s>162</s> 142 bytes

```
J::jb.z"\\bPPCG\\b""CGCC"." z¶NZI°Pÿúd(MÜ_BöIkxnqä'u)"." s6#~ÍN³=<nñu/GÎg"VS2~:J%"(^|\W)#%s\\b"*3%"([\da-f]{%d})"N$r"\1#\2\4\3"$)J
```

Here's a version without Pyth's string compression mechanisms (aka it's safe to copy-paste):

```
J::jb.z"\\bPPCG\\b""CGCC""\\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\\b""\\2\\1Coding Challenges"VS2~:J%"(^|\W)#%s\\b"*3%"([\da-f]{%d})"N$r"\1#\2\4\3"$)J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNS8NAEIYR7CX6F4Rl02JjSe1XghS9mENooSWgKGhU0mbzoU22ZjegUXvwKnrwJOjRH6AIPXgRkv9lTFK/DoWeZvaZ952dmeE5teK43Wwe98oBVNWeokhyEiCUZEmCZQiC@XC81N1rhS9K9BG968VcJ3oK7482o3HrJHw4C29y4WN47S6cRs/LPpdaiMiO5qLbbvi2sb7oRq/@qhzdmXBnqzZqtguweHip7nJsgaT/rNQTsK/qGm8cXBT0Kw528x5Uq6xaUxtqHea5dhynQzGKh01PcxzbNYHiB8EAEVAqAQnrCMh4YEwVYO@/IGkDCNVcnQAjqUwzJMU/R/ayKQHEpgj08SAx2QSwWs9gtq0fwlYqRoodv28BB3sI2C5FLkGAWpoLWEEQ15A@czzkEaaDqDZzDbZaqzeESch2Sm6TXUhLUcZNhv/N@UneEMRvp8hPlP@I@YmH1MYuiXn9Cw)

This ended up being really long because I tried to be as pedantic as possible with the regexes. I tried to compress every string possible, but most of them either didn't get smaller or couldn't be pasted into TIO properly.

Explanation:

```py
J::                      # definition of J to the following 2 regex replacements
   jb.z                  # input to first regex replacement: all input lines joined together
   "\\bPPCG\\b"          # first regex
   "CGCC"                # first replacement
   ."<compressed>"       # second regex: "\\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\\b"
   ."<compressed>"       # second replacement: "\\2\\1Coding Challenges"
VS2                      # loop twice, N = 1 or 2
  ~:J                    # some weird assignment: J = regex replace in J (would be J := (regex, replacement) if : was python's regex replace operator)
    %                    # third regex: string format
     "(^|\W)#%s\\b"      # format string
     *3                  # repeat 3 times:
       %"([\da-f]{%d})"N # string format, replace %d with N (the loop counter)
    $r"\1#\2\4\3"$       # third replacement: uses python raw literals because it's shorter than escaping the backslashes
    )                    # end for loop
J                        # print J
```

- -11 thanks to a better regex from Value Ink's Ruby answer
- -20 thanks to using a loop for both of the hex replacements, inspired by the Ruby and Perl answers

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>152</s> 145 bytes

*@ValueInk saves 7 bytes*

```perl
s/\bPPCG\b/CGCC/g;s/\bProgramming Puzzles( \S+ )(Code Golf)\b/$2$1Coding Challenges/g;for$a(1,2){$p="([a-f0-9]{$a})"x3;s/(^|\s)#\K$p\b/$2$4$3/gi}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BS8QwFITv/RWPbQ4NWtvuWlHEUw49iFDQm1VIt2kbSJOSlwXZdf@6MV1RL3t88@abmVlYVXqPWdPWNauaNmMVY9lwf1KsGSyfJqkHqHf7vRKYQPN8ATRhphNQGdXTgJA1KYKw2NjIlRJ6EBgyemMJT4rLNT2Q@WGVvPK0z9O7twPhR7r62ISS5P2zQRo3j2T@Cbomm2yQR@@XOdGZBWAs/LVHiwvQcd0hhDo4B4TnP3G6pENA6QRsjQqQRIh520cv468S53m/yNNuO8JkrACpndAowI1cQ1yWN7ei@zKzk0ajT5/Kq7zIfTp/Aw)

Comment: `( \S+ )(Code Golf)\b/$2$1Coding` saves 2 bytes. Also the last regex can end with just a `\b` instead of `(?=\s|$)`

Comment: I was working on that first one while you were typing that comment.  I've made the other change to save some bytes.  Thanks!

Comment: That `\s` should be `\W` instead, otherwise it fails [this case](https://tio.run/##JY1BC8IgAEb/ylgelLK5rR0iOnnYIYJBxyxwpTZwU7QgtvbXs1XXx/veZ4XTRQg@YXVV0ZLVCS0pTdTmR5xRjrdt06moevS9Fh5G7DCPEKTmKqLSaImmCchAOoGvRm9ca9Ep4aeGNA5wmC4yNAC7jeGRY0nw@jQAPqL4mU8n8PxiHs3YDth/aAXyRDVjCBejjcMzQuTb2HtjOh/wvliSlARsPw) (`-` is a non-alphanumeric character, so the substitution should be applied).

Comment: [137](https://tio.run/##bU7NS8MwFL/3r3iuBROka512DhF6iLCDCIV5sx6y9vUD0qQkGcLY325MJupll8d7v6/3m1GLwjmTkfLpqv6kpKrY9lRp1Ws@TaPsoTocjwINgXp3A5Qw1SJslejoidAyJuSdp13dflBSkns/1pTS@oWQsqD0Z9J6nyWbZfKgdLIqF8ldsvIhIZoNXAiUPZrFI9sylvXoXCgQXSgASsPf8yiowFguWwOdZy4ZPPnvOF@jNWBGi9Ao4U2jgZjvu@ht@EXiPO8CPB2aASalEUZpURoEO3AJcVGsN9hGz0peW7AqqHxC04Zy5wW/1GxHJY1LX4tlfpu7dP4G)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 192 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("\\bPPCG\\b","CGCC").replaceAll("\\bProgramming Puzzles( \\S+ )(Code Golf)\\b","$2$1Coding Challenges").replaceAll("\\B(#(?=([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}\\b).+?)(..??)(..??)\\b","$1$4$3")
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186729/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rZJdT8IwFIbv@RUnZQltYAsfYlSCRHdBvBBJ8I5xUbYOil1H1o5ECb8duzHQAH7EeNO157zn3XlOu6Arai@Cl60vqFLwSLlclwC41CwJqc9gkB0BRjrhcgY@LjaKdEx8UzKL0lRzHwYgoQtbZd8qJ2FLYYrvhMDI86bDods3H1RDbt91ETnJJ/EsoVGUGQ/TtzfBFAbPG1WBYDcOGPRjEZKdg9W0GiaWSd05FYLJGVMnlve4jHtdPK7b19QOJ@vWhqwbtebGeBCn2iPYcXr7tfBtWBdWC5FtJ2NaplNhmAq0VcwDiMxoCvrxBCjZzUUzpTHKAFE@kUPkFAniBA40R2pTn/1MBgpCIztXbZIf5fmJawWKawZ@LEwRV1Cm0yPn5/k@Xa7Xw0wTpf4cojhh@SVLxUDPqYRyu315xYLTvjz5E4tR/GP/nvxbz5/fYn5hOULxXLlcprq4stGr0ixy4lQ7S5PUQmL0kOVvYE9/RlJBlWruUjW7r2XoKdW/sZKOj3dNfe9XoG227w)